# With three I seep into notes, With two I don't want jokes

Tags: riddle, rhyme

- With five I'm not from bots.
- With four I connect the dots.
- With three I seep into notes.
- With two I don't want jokes.
- With one I have three eyes.

The line above is where the answer lies.

Hint:

> With one I have three *open* eyes.

Comment: The _line_ above, as in a specific line, or the _lines_ above?

Comment: ^ Or the blank space between the list and that line?

Comment: It's a riddle, my fingers are sealed.

Comment: @riskymysteries I think what would help a lot is a hint for the "With five I'm not from bots" part.

Comment: @riskymysteries Oh, I see you accepted an answer now.  I liked this puzzle, but the question for the first bullet could be better - rot13(Obgf (ebobgf) pregnvayl pna oyvax vs qrfvtarq gb - nxn n uhznabvq ebobg be bar jvgu oyvaxvat yvtugf).  The rhyming is nice, but not if it works against making the puzzle as clear as it could be.

Comment: @mjjf Thanks! My puzzles are sometimes intentionally vague. Just a note: the last line of the riddle is not there just to rhyme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As according to above answers, i just observe the fifth

With five I'm not from bots.

> Blink - bots don't blink (TCooper)

With four I connect the dots.

> Link - connects things (TCooper)

With three I seep into notes.

> Ink - it does that seeping thing (TCooper)

With two I don't want jokes.

> nk(No Kidding) (mjjf)

With one I have three eyes.

> Last k, also known as symbol for thousand 1000, which shows up like three open eyes

The line above is where the answer lies.

> The line above is "With one I have three eyes.". Eyes gives the hit of the answer *blink*.

Comment: I hope this is it, not knowing the final answer has been haunting me for two weeks now

Comment: On the bot part - rot13(Grpuavpnyyl n ebobg pna oyvax, whfg abg jvgu rlryvqf (hayrff qrfvtarq gb unir gurz, v.r. n uhznabvq ebobg).  Ebobgf naq bgure znpuvarf univat oyvaxvat YRQ yvtugf nyy gur gvzr!)  Nice outside-the-box thinking on the fifth bullet.

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer (I think)

With five I'm not from bots.

> Blink - bots don't blink

With four I connect the dots.

> Link - connects things

With three I seep into notes.

> Ink - it does that seeping thing

With two I don't want jokes.

> maybe in, like inside jokes, but not sure why you don't want them, or if you're in on the joke it's not being played on you?

With one I have three eyes.

> i? idk... this and two are why I put partial, but I think the first 3 fit too well not to post for someone else

Answer (score 2):

Giving this another shot based on the hint "No one's lying".  There are two possible meanings for this:

- There is no lie (more likely)
- It's not the *last* line that is lying, it is the *first* line.  I don't think this makes sense with the riddle.

With five I'm not from bots.

> links - maybe this has to do with robots.txt files in websites?; 5 letters

With four I connect the dots.

> link - links two dots; 4 letters

With three I seep into notes.

> ink - when used to write on paper, ink literally seeps into the page; 3 letters

With two I don't want jokes.

> nk - No Kidding (abbreviation); 2 letters

With one I have three eyes.

> Maybe instead of "i"s, this is referring to a [third eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_eye).  However I can't think of a single letter that would give this meaning.

> The other option is what I had originally thought - the answer has to ensure that there are only three "i"s in the other 4 answers (or be a lie).  The only narrowing I can do is that it isn't "i" in that case (if my other answers are right).

The line above is where the answer lies.

> the answer to the line directly above contains the answer to the riddle

The answer is:

> No idea :)

Comment: @riskymysteries Thank you for the hint!  Still can't quite get it though.  I added some new postulations.

Comment: K is formed from 3 I's, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm… I'm going to combine the two answers from mjjf and TCooper(and add my answer).

the word is

> blink

> link

for 4,

> ink

for 3,

> nk

for 2, and

> a letter with three *holes*(eyes)

for 1.

Comment: Hint: No one's lying.

Comment: I was just combining answers. I myself have no idea how to solve it.